# In an SQL query, is "TOP 1" a reliable substitute for aggregate functions such MIN() or MAX()..?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

Is "TOP 1" a reliable substitute for aggregate functions such as MIN() and MAX()..? Shown below is a basic query in Access 2007, to determine the first time a customer ordered a certain product during a certain month. The DBMS system is probably irrelevant, since this question could apply to any system.

In this query, "TOP 1" is used in combination with ORDER BY on the date field. This returns one record, that being the oldest by date. But...is this ok..? What can go wrong..? Is there a better way..?

```
SELECT TOP 1 DAACCT, DAITEM, DAQTY, DAIDAT

FROM fqlOrdersGrandHistory

WHERE DAACCT="T7414" AND DAITEM="45234" AND (DAIDAT>=20170501 AND DAIDAT<=20170531)

ORDER BY DAIDAT;
```

Comment: _"But...is this ok..?"_ Yes, if you don't have multiple records with the same date. But it's not the same as `MIN` and `MAX`

Comment: Sounds like XY problem. I'm guessing you are "trying to use an aggregate function but also have other columns displayed" but you don't want to group them? There are ways to address that problem. Ordering and using select top 1 is a workaround, as Tim said, assuming you are ordering by unique values.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. I have a query that returns a set of invoices, and I want to narrow that down to the one with the oldest date. So at minimum I need the fields for invoice number and date. If I use MIN() in that scenario, it doesn't work because of the differing invoice numbers. Although I understand it's because each record and all its fields are evaluated as a whole, I have yet to find/understand a solution to this basic problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reliable is a subjective term. Yes, `TOP 1` will give you a result, as will `MAX()` or `MIN()`. It depends on what you are after.

If you look for a specific user only (as you appear to be in this case) and sort by DATE ascending and use `TOP 1`, you will get all of the details for that one record. However, if you are looking for the first purchase of every user in the table, then TOP 1 will only give you the info for the very first person who made an order.

On the other hand, if you use `SELECT DAACCT, MIN(DAIDAT) FROM table GROUP BY DAACCT` then you will get the earliest purchase for each user. This assumes you are storing the `DAIDAT` as a date format with a time component, not just the date value itself. If you do that, you open yourself up to multiple possible records.

TL;DR: If you stick with the concept of the query 1) looking for a very specific user for 2) a very specific product and 3) your dates are stored as proper dates, `TOP 1` will be better to use than an aggregate function. If one of these three conditions are not met, reevaluate.

Comment: This system stores the dates as a Long Integer, in the format YYYYMMDD. So for instance today would be 20170628. After discussing the issue with a coworker, TOP 1 should work. If there are multiple invoices that day, that's ok just pick one since it's the date we're after. The invoice number in incidental and can be included for reference.

Answer (score 1):

`TOP` is used to limit the fetched rows and yes it's fine unless you have multiple records with same data. Not sure how it's relates to `Min()` or `Max()` ...  you use `Min()` or `Max()` aggregate function when you are grouping the rows using `Group By`. Even if you don't specify a `group by` grouping happens on the entire result set

Comment: You can also use `MIN`/`MAX` with `WHERE`(which he used). But of course it's not the same as `TOP 1` which picks the values from a single record whereas `MIN` and `MAX` might pick out the values from different records.

Comment: There are a couple more layers to the problem. I just discussed the issue of uniqueness with a coworker. What I'll need to do is get the oldest date(s) from the query, which I was just told could lead to multiple results, since we do in some cases send multiple invoices to one customer on the same day. So...then I need to get any of those numbers and pick one with TOP 1 because it's the resulting date that's the purpose of this query. So now that I think about it...I guess TOP 1 will work fine for this.

Answer (score 1):

It is OK if either one field or a combination of fields of the selected fields is unique.

If not, the result set will contain all the records where the field or combination match. To avoid this, always include, say, an autonumber field in the selected fields.